# Store and access elements between pages navigation

Tags: watir, pageobjects

I'm new to watir and page objects.
I have defined two pages, SearchPage and ReportsPage; On SearchPage I have button reports, I clicked on that and ReportPage was opened, I want to be able to use an element value from SearchPage on ReportsPage for making some assertions.

How can I store a value from page SearchPage and use it on ReportPage?

I have SearchPage defined like that:

```
class SearchPage < Browser
  URL = "http://localhost:3000/"

  def open
    @browser.goto URL
    self
  end



  def reports_link
    @browser.link(href: '/reports')
  end

  def name_field
    @browser.div(class: 'M0Z8m _1_jJ7')

  end
```

And ReportsPage:

```
class ReportPage < Browser
  URL = "http://localhost:3000/reports"

  def report_value
    @browser.element(class: '_1CV_I')
  end
end
```

And Browser page defined like that:

```
class Browser
  def initialize(browser)
    @browser = browser
  end
end
```

I click on reports link like this on a step :

```
Given (/^I navigate to application$/) do
  @searchPage = SearchgPage.new(@browser);
  @searchPage.open; sleep 1

end

When (/^I click on reports$/) do
@search_page.reports_link.click
```

ReportPage was loaded and on *Then* step I'll need value of field *name_field* from *SearchPAge*. How can I access that value because with @search_page is not working as it is expected, as that page is not loaded any more.

Comment: Add the code part please otherwise how someone can know what you are actually doing?

Comment: Update the question with necessary detail please.

Comment: @Rajagopalan I added the code part, Thanks!